# Bash not working in TTY/gnome-termina/Xterm

Tags: command-line, bash, tty

I opened the terminal today and all I could see was this white blinking bar:

[image: terminal screenshot]

I opened Xterm and there is the same problem. Also, TTY doesn't work well, I can login and then I cannot type anything. I checked basic files like `.bashrc` `.profile`, and all the stuff inside `/etc` and I changed nothing there. I need to get my terminal back :(

Comment: Does pressing CTRL-C bring you back to the prompt ?

Comment: no it doesn't even show user@machie

Comment: Rename `~/.bashrc` to a different name and then relaunch your terminal and see if that works ... Also check in your gnome-terminal preferences under the active profile to see if the command tab has any of the top two check boxes ticked and un-tick them ... Also, have you altered your system Python version by any chance?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Also i created another user to see if it's user specific, and it was. I updated node and python3 back that day and it seems that it added something to .bashrc, i compared these files between old and new user and just copied new user version and it works just fine.